# How to implemen shadertoy code into three.js - clarifying the details

Tags: three.js, glsl, webgl, fragment-shader, vertex-buffer

So here is a previous question:
[How to implement a ShaderToy shader in three.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24820004/how-to-implement-a-shadertoy-shader-in-three-js)

Tried to implement the steps from the link above into this code unsucessfully:
[three.js/blob/master/examples/webgl_shader.html](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/webgl_shader.html)

So I replaced the original vertex shader and the origianl fragment shader so I got this code:

```
<script id="vertexShader" type="x-shader/x-vertex">
    varying vec2 vUv; 
    void main()
    {

     vUv = uv;

        vec4 mvPosition = modelViewMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0 );
        gl_Position = projectionMatrix * mvPosition;    
    }
</script>

<script id="fragmentShader" type="x-shader/x-fragment">


    uniform float iGlobalTime;
    uniform sampler2D iChannel0;
    uniform sampler2D iChannel1;

    varying vec2 vUv; 

    void main(void)
    {
        vec2 p = -1.0 + 2.0 *vUv;
        vec2 q = p - vec2(0.5, 0.5);

        q.x += sin(iGlobalTime* 0.6) * 0.2;
        q.y += cos(iGlobalTime* 0.4) * 0.3;

        float len = length(q);

        float a = atan(q.y, q.x) + iGlobalTime * 0.3;
        float b = atan(q.y, q.x) + iGlobalTime * 0.3;
        float r1 = 0.3 / len + iGlobalTime * 0.5;
        float r2 = 0.2 / len + iGlobalTime * 0.5;

        float m = (1.0 + sin(iGlobalTime * 0.5)) / 2.0;
        vec4 tex1 = texture2D(iChannel0, vec2(a + 0.1 / len, r1 ));
        vec4 tex2 = texture2D(iChannel1, vec2(b + 0.1 / len, r2 ));
        vec3 col = vec3(mix(tex1, tex2, m));
        gl_FragColor = vec4(col * len * 1.5, 1.0);
    }
</script>
```

This is clear but how and Where to implement the tuniform:

```
var tuniform = {


        iGlobalTime:    { type: 'f', value: 0.1 },
        iChannel0:  { type: 't', value: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( 'textures/tex07.jpg') },
        iChannel1:  { type: 't', value: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( 'textures/infi.jpg' ) },


    };
```

and the iGlobalTime parts?

```
tuniform.iChannel0.value.wrapS = tuniform.iChannel0.value.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
tuniform.iChannel1.value.wrapS = tuniform.iChannel1.value.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
```

So my question is: how to modify this code (or any thrre.js code):
[three.js/blob/master/examples/webgl_shader.html](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/webgl_shader.html)

to display a working shadertoy example which includes iGlobalTime as well?

==================== EITED PART STARTS HERE =========================

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>three.js webgl - shader [Monjori]</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
        <style>
            body {
                color: #ffffff;
                font-family:Monospace;
                font-size:13px;
                text-align:center;
                font-weight: bold;

                background-color: #000000;
                margin: 0px;
                overflow: hidden;
            }

            #info {
                position: absolute;
                top: 0px; width: 100%;
                padding: 5px;
            }

            a {

                color: #ffffff;
            }

            #oldie a { color:#da0 }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div id="container"></div>
        <div id="info"><a href="http://threejs.org" target="_blank">three.js</a> - shader demo. featuring <a href="http://www.pouet.net/prod.php?which=52761" target="_blank">Monjori by Mic</a></div>

        <script src="../build/three.min.js"></script>

        <script src="js/Detector.js"></script>
        <script src="js/libs/stats.min.js"></script>

        <script id="vertexShader" type="x-shader/x-vertex">
            varying vec2 vUv; 
            void main()
            {
            vUv = uv;
                vec4 mvPosition = modelViewMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0 );
                gl_Position = projectionMatrix * mvPosition;    
            }
        </script>

        <script id="fragmentShader" type="x-shader/x-fragment">


            uniform float iGlobalTime;
            uniform sampler2D iChannel0;
            uniform sampler2D iChannel1;

            varying vec2 vUv; 

            void main(void)
            {
                vec2 p = -1.0 + 2.0 *vUv;
                vec2 q = p - vec2(0.5, 0.5);

                q.x += sin(iGlobalTime* 0.6) * 0.2;
                q.y += cos(iGlobalTime* 0.4) * 0.3;

                float len = length(q);

                float a = atan(q.y, q.x) + iGlobalTime * 0.3;
                float b = atan(q.y, q.x) + iGlobalTime * 0.3;
                float r1 = 0.3 / len + iGlobalTime * 0.5;
                float r2 = 0.2 / len + iGlobalTime * 0.5;

                float m = (1.0 + sin(iGlobalTime * 0.5)) / 2.0;
                vec4 tex1 = texture2D(iChannel0, vec2(a + 0.1 / len, r1 ));
                vec4 tex2 = texture2D(iChannel1, vec2(b + 0.1 / len, r2 ));
                vec3 col = vec3(mix(tex1, tex2, m));
                gl_FragColor = vec4(col * len * 1.5, 1.0);
            }
        </script>

        <script>

            if ( ! Detector.webgl ) Detector.addGetWebGLMessage();

            var container, stats;

            var camera, scene, renderer;

            var uniforms;

            init();
            animate();

            function init() {

                container = document.getElementById( 'container' );

                camera = new THREE.Camera();
                camera.position.z = 1;

                scene = new THREE.Scene();

                var geometry = new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry( 2, 2 );

                uniforms = {
                    time: { type: "f", value: 1.0 },
                    resolution: { type: "v2", value: new THREE.Vector2() }
                };

                var material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial( {

                    uniforms: uniforms,
                    vertexShader: document.getElementById( 'vertexShader' ).textContent,
                    fragmentShader: document.getElementById( 'fragmentShader' ).textContent

                } );

                var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
                scene.add( mesh );

                renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
                renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
                container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

                stats = new Stats();
                stats.domElement.style.position = 'absolute';
                stats.domElement.style.top = '0px';
                container.appendChild( stats.domElement );

                onWindowResize();

                window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );

            }

            function onWindowResize( event ) {
                renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

                uniforms.resolution.value.x = renderer.domElement.width;
                uniforms.resolution.value.y = renderer.domElement.height;
            }
            //

            function animate() {

                requestAnimationFrame( animate );

                render();
                stats.update();

            }

            function render() {

                var tuniform = {

                        iGlobalTime:    { type: 'f', value: 0.1 },
                        iChannel0:  { type: 't', value: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( 'textures/brick_bump.jpg') },
                        iChannel1:  { type: 't', value: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( 'textures/brick_bump.jpg' ) },

                    };
                    tuniform.iChannel0.value.wrapS = tuniform.iChannel0.value.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
                    tuniform.iChannel1.value.wrapS = tuniform.iChannel1.value.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;


                    delta=clock.getDelta();
                    tuniform.iGlobalTime.value += delta;

                    uniforms.time.value += 0.05;

                    renderer.render( scene, camera );

            }

        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The things you ask for are all covered within the answer your linked

Comment: Not detailed enough for me. I'm a newcomer to three.js. I'm looking for any piece of more specific code.

Comment: search for `shadertoy` in this page http://blog.2pha.com/experimenting-threejs-shaders-and-shadermaterial

Comment: I've already seen this example. My probelm is: none of these code contains e.g. "iGlobalTime". These axamples are too simple. I can display such basic shaders but complex ones. I would like to know where should I implement "delta=clock.getDelta(); [...]" I would like to display more complex shadertoys. The original example says e.g.: "In your THREEJS code set up". What  is my "THREEJS code"? The .html file? So  implement these pieces of code into function animate() or into function render()? Please explain or if possible copy paste a working complex example (including e.g. "iGlobalTime")

Comment: The first snippet after the ones you copied from the linked question contains exactly that, passing iGlobalTime to the shader...

Comment: you should get the delta and send it to your shader in your render loop.

Comment: 2pha: this comment was very helpful: this is what I need. As you said I put delta into my renderer part. Please see my eited original question. I copied my complete .html code into my original question. Please review it since it only displays a black screen. Console log says that: "Uncaught ReferenceError: vshader is not defined". I would need to make sure, that all the code parts of the other(original) question are the right place in my code.

Comment: Although I'm not 100% sure what you are trying to do. I am pretty sure you do not want to be creating new objects and materials in your render loop. You should be just calculating a new delta and sending this to the to the shader that has already been created.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Updated my renderer loop. Removed object and extra material. We are almost done. I'm trying to calculate the new delta and sending it to the shader, but I'm getting following error in the consoloe log: "Uncaught ReferenceError: clock is not defined". May I ask you please to take a look at my renderer loop code. What's wrong with this two lines? "delta=clock.getDelta(); tuniform.iGlobalTime.value += delta;" Why am I getting the above mentioned error?

Comment: Added "clock = new THREE.Clock();"  to my function init() part -> console log error has been disappeared but I only can see a black screen.

Comment: What am I trying to do? I'm looking for the Simplest three.js code which can display the most complex shadertoys. E.g. this one: https://www.shadertoy.com/view/Mds3Rn

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To convert any shader from shadertoy to a three.js shader, you just have to have the correct variables/uniforms. Shadertoy has uniforms available that three.js shaders do not by default. Shadertoy has the iResolution uniform for example, which you will not have in a three.js shader as Shadertoy is for rendering on a flat canvas rather than a 3d object. iGlobalTime is also one of these uniforms that is not in a three.js shader by default.

In the code you posted, you have defined the iGlobalTime uniform corrrectly, you just need create a THREE.Clock once when you code first runs, then you need to update the uniform in your render function.

```
uniforms.iGlobalTime.value = clock.getElapsedTime();
```

I have implemented this [matrix style shader](https://www.shadertoy.com/view/MlfXzN) which uses iGlobalTime in three.js [here](https://2pha.com/blog/demos/threejs/shaders/matrix.html)

Comment: Cool. Downloaded. It's just working perfectly. Will use this source as a good starting point for future researches. However I just considered that I cannot simply copy-paste shadertoy fragment shaders into your code. Just came some questions to my mind 1. Why have you deleted that two lines from fragment shader's main() function. 2. In the same are, in the fragment shader's main() function why have you replaced matrix(st) to matrix(vUv). So what are the most important steps when I would like to copy-paste a shaertoy? What should I change in the code comparing to the original shadertoy code?

Comment: shadertoy uses the x and y coordinates of the canvas, whereas a three.js material shader uses the UV coordinates of the model. I don't think you will ever be able to simply copy and paste from shadertoy without making some changes. I have many examples of simple shaders at: http://blog.2pha.com/experimenting-threejs-shaders-and-shadermaterial

Comment: If my answer did infact answer your question, please accept it.

Comment: Answered my questions perfectly. Thank you.