# Threejs error when trying to implement ShaderToy

Tags: javascript, glsl, webgl

first time poster... 
I've been through SO looking at threejs/shadertoy stuff but haven't been able to find this particular issue.  I'm hoping someone can help.


I'm attempting to bring this shadertoy:https://www.shadertoy.com/view/ltfXWr# into a simple html file and use threejs to display it.  I followed the general idea behind this: [How to implement a ShaderToy shader in three.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24820004/how-to-implement-a-shadertoy-shader-in-three-js)

and added some uniforms at the top of my fragment shader to make up for the unique stuff (iResolution, iMouse,etc) Shadertoy uses. Outside of this I haven't adjusted any of the code from what you can see of the shadertoy source. 

When I run the code I I receive the following error:

```
THREE.WebGLProgram: shader error:  0 gl.VALIDATE_STATUS false gl.getProgramInfoLog invalid shaders  ERROR: 0:168: 'GL_OES_standard_derivatives' : extension is disabled<br>
ERROR: 0:188: 'xy' :  field selection requires structure, vector, or matrix on left hand side <br>
ERROR: 0:188: 'y' :  field selection requires structure, vector, or matrix on left hand side <br>
ERROR: 0:188: 'res' : redefinition <br>
ERROR: 0:189: 'y' :  field selection requires structure, vector, or matrix on left hand side <br>
ERROR: 0:189: 'uv' : redefinition <br>
ERROR: 0:191: 'xy' :  field selection requires structure, vector, or matrix on left hand side <br>
ERROR: 0:191: 'xy' :  field selection requires structure, vector, or matrix on left hand side <br>
ERROR: 0:191: 'constructor' : not enough data provided for construction
```

I'm just not entirely sure what to do at this point.  I'm new to a lot of this and it could well be that I'm missing something obvious.
My (not functioning, but you can see the error) codepen is here: http://codepen.io/ikimono/pen/RWVJYv

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I've made some progress in realizing that my 'uniform float iMouse' and iResolution were of the wrong type.  (needed to be uniform vec4 and uniform vec2 respectively).  This is for Threejs r72 btw.   I've updated my pen.  The errors now read:  THREE.WebGLProgram: shader error:  0 gl.VALIDATE_STATUS false gl.getProgramInfoLog invalid shaders  ERROR: 0:328: 'GL_OES_standard_derivatives' : extension is disabled
ERROR: 0:348: 'res' : redefinition 
ERROR: 0:349: 'uv' : redefinition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Redefinition errors mean that you already defined a variable. You need to declare the type of a variable only when you define it.

You need to change these:

```
vec2 uv = -1.0 + 2.0 *vUv;
vec2 res = -1.0 + 2.0 *vUv;
vec2 res = iResolution.xy / iResolution.y;
vec2 uv = fragCoord.xy / iResolution.y;
```

To these:

```
vec2 uv = -1.0 + 2.0 *vUv;
vec2 res = -1.0 + 2.0 *vUv;
res = iResolution.xy / iResolution.y;
uv = fragCoord.xy / iResolution.y;
```

**Edit:**

For the extension error, it means that you need to enable the `GL_OES_standard_derivatives` extension, if supported by you graphic card.
To check if the extension is available you can use this to print the list of available extensions to the console:

```
console.log(gl.getSupportedExtensions());
```

Where `gl` is your WebGL context.

If the extension is effectively available, you can enable it by calling this:

```
gl.getExtension('OES_texture_float');
```

And add this at the beginning of your shader:

```
#ifdef GL_OES_standard_derivatives
    #extension GL_OES_standard_derivatives : enable
#endif
```

Check [this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGL_API/Using_Extensions) for more information.

Comment: Thank you Elie that definitely took care of those errors.  Any idea about the "THREE.WebGLProgram: shader error:  0 gl.VALIDATE_STATUS false gl.getProgramInfoLog invalid shaders  ERROR: 0:328: 'GL_OES_standard_derivatives' : extension is disabled"?   That's the remaining error I have now.  Google has been unhelpful...

Comment: Thank you, very helpful!