# what is surfacePosition varying in glslsandbox.com

Tags: glsl, shader

What difference between vUv and surfacePosition varying?

Comment: I just posted an answer to your GLSL Sandbox question, can you leave that question here and make the ShaderToy question a new post?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In GLSL Sandbox, the `varying vec2 surfacePosition` is a position on a scrollable, zoomable surface.  In its default position, the `y` coordinates range from `-1.0` to `1.0`, and the `x` coordinates have a similar range that has been scaled according to the window's aspect ratio.

This is useful for example in fractal renderers, to allow the user to pan & zoom the fractal.  Here's a trivial Mandelbrot Set.  Click the "hide code" button in the upper-left, then use left-mouse to pan and right-mouse to zoom.

http://glslsandbox.com/e#30483.0

```
uniform float time;
uniform vec2 mouse;
uniform vec2 resolution;

varying vec2 surfacePosition;

const float max_its = 100.;

float mandelbrot(vec2 z){
    vec2 c = z;
    for(float i=0.;i<max_its;i++){
        if(dot(z,z)>4.) return i;
        z = vec2(z.x*z.x-z.y*z.y,2.*z.x*z.y)+c;
    }
    return max_its;
}


void main( void ) {
    vec2 p = surfacePosition;
    gl_FragColor = vec4(mandelbrot(p)/max_its);
}
```

The same technique can be abused to provide pan & zoom in 3D.  Here's the Mandelbulb, for example.  It's heavier on your GPU, but hide the code and you can pan & zoom this too.

http://glslsandbox.com/e#1893.0

Comment: thanks but vUv varying not covered. What difference between vUv vs surfacePosition?

Comment: I'm not a ShaderToy expert, but as far as I can tell, `vUv` is not part of ShaderToy itself, instead it's part of a [typical way to port ShaderToy samples to systems like Three.js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24820004/how-to-implement-a-shadertoy-shader-in-three-js).  The user may want the model's texture coordinates to be used in place of screen coordinates (`gl_FragCoord.xy`) or `surfacePosition` coordinates.  So `vUv` represents the model's own texture coordinate, which is substituted in for screen or surface coordinates.