# Porting frame buffer Shadertoy to three.js

Tags: three.js, webgl, porting, fragment-shader, framebuffer

I want to port this shader: https://www.shadertoy.com/view/ldcGDX, to three.js. I'm new with fragment shaders but I'm using this thread as a semi-guide for how to port this type of frame buffer shader: https://discourse.threejs.org/t/basi...sl-shaders/409

Sadly, there seem to be lots of variables that needs to be converted in ways that are unknown for me. And the resources for this type of porting is sparse to say the least. So i'm asking all the shader masters out there for some kind of guidance of how to port this code/variables to make the port successful. Or if someone have good information to direct me to!

Thank you!

Comment: What have you tried? There's this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36983769/export-from-shadertoy-to-three-js?rq=1

Comment: I'm trying to find resources for how shadertoy shaders differ from shaders in three js when it comes to the actual code. How the UVs are setup and differences in the variable names etc etc. I've seen the link you refer to, and it's a good source for some stuff, but there are more things that needs to change. I'm trying to collect multiple sources to be able to port every line of code successfully. Line by line. Thx for your respons!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Export from Shadertoy to Three.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36983769/export-from-shadertoy-to-three-js)