# Converting shader from Shadertoy to Three.js will not display

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am very new to OpenGL/WebGL and am trying to render this shadertoy in WebGL/three.js below: https://www.shadertoy.com/view/mlsXWn

```
        // import * as THREE from 'three';

        // import Stats from 'three/addons/libs/stats.module.js';
        // import { GUI } from 'three/addons/libs/lil-gui.module.min.js';
        var start = new Date();
        const container = document.body;

        const FOV = 45;
        const NEAR = 0.1;
        const FAR = 1000;
        let height = container.clientHeight;
        let width = container.clientWidth;
        const ASPECT = width / height;

        const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true });
        renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio || 1);
        renderer.setClearColor(0x000000);

        const canvas = renderer.domElement;

        const scene = new THREE.Scene();

        const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(FOV, ASPECT, NEAR, FAR);
        camera.position.set(-2, 2, 2);
        camera.target = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0);
        let theta = 0;
        const radius = 100;
        const resolution = new THREE.Vector2(width, height);
        const matNormal = new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial();

        const floorGeo = new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry(2.0, 2.0);
        const floor = new THREE.Mesh(floorGeo, matNormal);
        floor.position.set(0, -0.5, 0);
        floor.rotation.x = -((Math.PI * 90) / 180);

        const sphereGeo = new THREE.SphereBufferGeometry(0.5, 32, 32);
        const sphere = new THREE.Mesh(sphereGeo, matNormal);

        scene.add(floor);
        scene.add(sphere);
        scene.add(camera);
        var elapsed = new Date() - start;
        const VERTEX = `
varying vec2 vUv;
uniform float iTime;
uniform sampler2D tDiffuse;
uniform vec2 iResolution;
// Inputs
uniform sampler2D u_velocity;
uniform sampler2D u_density;

void main() {
    vec4 mvPosition = modelViewMatrix * vec4(position, 1.);
    gl_Position = projectionMatrix * mvPosition;
    vUv = uv;
}
`;
        const FRAGMENT = `//Adapted from https://www.shadertoy.com/view/tdG3Rd#
varying vec2 vUv;


//Other
float u_dt;
float u_diff;
float u_visc;
float prevTime;
float currTime;

void updateVars(){
    u_dt = currTime - prevTime;
    u_diff = sin(iTime*0.01);
    u_visc = 1.0;
    prevTime = currTime;
    currTime = iTime*0.01;
    
}
float colormap_red(float x) {
    if (x < 0.0) {
        return 0.0 / 255.0;
    } else if (x < 20049.0 / 82979.0) {
        return (95.79 * x + 54.51) / 255.0;
    } else {
        return 0.5;
    }
}

float colormap_green(float x) {
    if (x < 20049.0 / 82979.0) {
        return 0.2;
    } else if (x < 327013.0 / 810990.0) {
        return (8546482679670.0 / 10875673217.0 * x - 2064961390770.0 / 10875673217.0) / 255.0;
    } else if (x <= 1.0) {
        return (1038067.0 / 483977.0 * x + 19607415.0 / 483977.0) / 255.0;
    } else {
        return 0.4;
    }
}

float colormap_blue(float x) {
    if (x < 0.0) {
        return 95.0 / 255.0;
    } else if (x < 7249.0 / 82979.0) {
        return (8299.79 * x + 54.51) / 255.0;
    } else if (x < 20049.0 / 82979.0) {
        return 127.0 / 255.0;
    } else if (x < 327013.0 / 810990.0) {
        return (7922.02249341361393720147485376583 * x - 64.364790735602331034989206222672) / 255.0;
    } else {
        return 1.0;
    }
}

vec4 colormap(float x) {
    return vec4(colormap_red(x), colormap_green(x), colormap_blue(x), 1.0);
}

// https://iquilezles.org/articles/warp
/*float noise(vec2 x )
{
    vec2 p = floor(x);
    vec2 f = fract(x);
    f = f*f*(3.0-2.0*f);
    float a = texture2D(iChannel0,(p+vec2(0.5,0.5),lod)/256.0,0.0).x;
    float b = texture2D(iChannel0,(p+vec2(1.5,0.5),lod)/256.0,0.0).x;
    float c = texture2D(iChannel0,(p+vec2(0.5,1.5),lod)/256.0,0.0).x;
    float d = texture2D(iChannel0,(p+vec2(1.5,1.5),lod)/256.0,0.0).x;
    return mix(mix( a, b,f.x), mix( c, d,f.x),f.y);
}*/


float rand(vec2 n) { 
    return fract(sin(dot(n, vec2(18.9898, 14.1414))) * 43758.5453);
}

float noise(vec2 p){
    vec2 ip = floor(p);
    vec2 u = fract(p);
    u = u*u*(3.0-2.0*u);

    float res = mix(
        mix(rand(ip),rand(ip+vec2(1.0,0.0)),u.x),
        mix(rand(ip+vec2(0.0,1.0)),rand(ip+vec2(1.0,1.0)),u.x),u.y);
    return res*res;
}

const mat2 mtx = mat2( 0.80,  0.60, -0.60,  0.80 );

float fbm( vec2 p )
{
    float f = 0.0;

    f += 0.700000*noise( p + iTime *0.01  ); p = mtx*p*2.02;
    f += 0.001250*noise( p ); p = mtx*p*2.01;
    f += 0.250000*noise( p ); p = mtx*p*2.03;
    f += 0.025000*noise( p ); p = mtx*p*2.01;
    f += 0.062500*noise( p ); p = mtx*p*2.04;
    f += 0.015625*noise( p + sin(iTime*0.01) );

    return f/0.96875;
}

float pattern( in vec2 p )
{
    return fbm( p + fbm( p + fbm( p ) ) );
}
//out vec4 gl_fragColor, in vec2 fragCoord
void main()
{
    updateVars();
    vec2 uv = vUv.x;
    float shade = pattern(uv);
    
    //BREAK
    vec2 p = (vUv) * 2.0 - 1.0;
    vec2 xy = p * vec2(iResolution.x / iResolution.y, 1);

    vec2 velocity = texture2D(u_velocity, xy).xy;
    float density = texture2D(u_density, xy).x+sin(iTime*0.01);

    // Advection
    vec2 advection = texture2D(u_velocity, xy - u_dt * velocity).xy;

    // Diffusion
    vec2 diffusion = (texture2D(u_velocity, xy + vec2(u_diff, 0.1)).xy +
                          texture2D(u_velocity, xy - vec2(u_diff, 0.1)).xy +
    texture2D(u_velocity, xy + vec2(1.0, u_diff)).xy +
    texture2D(u_velocity, xy - vec2(1.0, u_diff)).xy) / 4.0;

    // Viscosity
    vec2 viscosity = (texture2D(u_velocity, xy + vec2(u_visc, 0.1)).xy +
                      texture2D(u_velocity, xy - vec2(u_visc, 0.1)).xy +
                      texture2D(u_velocity, xy + vec2(0.1, u_visc)).xy +
                      texture2D(u_velocity, xy - vec2(0.1, u_visc)).xy -
                      4.0 * texture2D(u_velocity, xy).xy) / (u_visc * u_visc);

    // Update velocity and density
    velocity = advection + diffusion + viscosity;
    density = texture2D(u_density, xy - u_dt * velocity).x;

    gl_fragColor = vec4(colormap(shade).rgb * (density+0.1), shade);
    // return gl_fragColor;
}`;
 

        function onWindowResize() {

            camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
            camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

            renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
            pass.uniforms.iResolution.value.set(width, height);
        }

        //

        const drawShader = {
            uniforms: {
                tDiffuse: { type: 't', value: null },
                iResolution: { type: 'v2', value: resolution },
                iTime: {type: 'float', value: elapsed},
                u_velocity: { type: 't', value: null },
                u_density: { type: 't', value: null },
            },
            vertexShader: VERTEX,
            fragmentShader: FRAGMENT,
        };

        const composer = new THREE.EffectComposer(renderer);
        composer.addPass(new THREE.RenderPass(scene, camera));

        const pass = new THREE.ShaderPass(drawShader);
        pass.renderToScreen = true;
        composer.addPass(pass);

        const resize = (width, height) => {
        camera.aspect = width / height;
        camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

        composer.setSize(width, height);

        renderer.setSize(width, height);
        };


        const render = () => {
            const tmpHeight = container.clientHeight;
            const tmpWidth = container.clientWidth;
            if (tmpHeight !== height || tmpWidth !== width) {
            height = tmpHeight;
            width = tmpWidth;
            resize(width, height);
            }

            controls.update();

            // renderer.render(scene, camera);
            composer.render();
            var elapsed = new Date() - start;
            requestAnimationFrame(render);
        };
```

I've tried to use three.js and following [this tutorial](https://medium.com/hackernoon/converting-shaders-from-shadertoy-to-threejs-fe17480ed5c6) but I'm only slowly understanding bits and pieces; I still feel like like I'm missing some key aspect. Additionally, I am not getting any console errors but rather just nothing is rendering. I got the render from the tutorial to work, but I can't get my own shadertoy to render. I've tried moving around the uniforms and I tried to make sure I was defining all of my uniforms as well, but to no avail.

Edit #1: I was able to solve my initial issue by uncommenting the line with "renderer.render" but now my fragment shader (shown below) will unfortunately not compile.

```
const FRAGMENT = `//Adapted from https://www.shadertoy.com/view/tdG3Rd#
varying vec2 vUv;

uniform float iTime;
uniform sampler2D tDiffuse;
uniform vec2 iResolution;
// Inputs
uniform sampler2D u_velocity;
uniform sampler2D u_density;

//Other
float u_dt;
float u_diff;
float u_visc;
float prevTime;
float currTime;

void updateVars(){
    u_dt = currTime - prevTime;
    u_diff = sin(iTime*0.01);
    u_visc = 1.0;
    prevTime = currTime;
    currTime = iTime*0.01;
    
}
float colormap_red(float x) {
    if (x < 0.0) {
        return 0.0 / 255.0;
    } else if (x < 20049.0 / 82979.0) {
        return (95.79 * x + 54.51) / 255.0;
    } else {
        return 0.5;
    }
}

float colormap_green(float x) {
    if (x < 20049.0 / 82979.0) {
        return 0.2;
    } else if (x < 327013.0 / 810990.0) {
        return (8546482679670.0 / 10875673217.0 * x - 2064961390770.0 / 10875673217.0) / 255.0;
    } else if (x <= 1.0) {
        return (1038067.0 / 483977.0 * x + 19607415.0 / 483977.0) / 255.0;
    } else {
        return 0.4;
    }
}

float colormap_blue(float x) {
    if (x < 0.0) {
        return 95.0 / 255.0;
    } else if (x < 7249.0 / 82979.0) {
        return (8299.79 * x + 54.51) / 255.0;
    } else if (x < 20049.0 / 82979.0) {
        return 127.0 / 255.0;
    } else if (x < 327013.0 / 810990.0) {
        return (7922.02249341361393720147485376583 * x - 64.364790735602331034989206222672) / 255.0;
    } else {
        return 1.0;
    }
}

vec4 colormap(float x) {
    return vec4(colormap_red(x), colormap_green(x), colormap_blue(x), 1.0);
}

// https://iquilezles.org/articles/warp
/*float noise(vec2 x )
{
    vec2 p = floor(x);
    vec2 f = fract(x);
    f = f*f*(3.0-2.0*f);
    float a = texture2D(iChannel0,(p+vec2(0.5,0.5),lod)/256.0,0.0).x;
    float b = texture2D(iChannel0,(p+vec2(1.5,0.5),lod)/256.0,0.0).x;
    float c = texture2D(iChannel0,(p+vec2(0.5,1.5),lod)/256.0,0.0).x;
    float d = texture2D(iChannel0,(p+vec2(1.5,1.5),lod)/256.0,0.0).x;
    return mix(mix( a, b,f.x), mix( c, d,f.x),f.y);
}*/


float rand(vec2 n) { 
    return fract(sin(dot(n, vec2(18.9898, 14.1414))) * 43758.5453);
}

float noise(vec2 p){
    vec2 ip = floor(p);
    vec2 u = fract(p);
    u = u*u*(3.0-2.0*u);

    float res = mix(
        mix(rand(ip),rand(ip+vec2(1.0,0.0)),u.x),
        mix(rand(ip+vec2(0.0,1.0)),rand(ip+vec2(1.0,1.0)),u.x),u.y);
    return res*res;
}

const mat2 mtx = mat2( 0.80,  0.60, -0.60,  0.80 );

float fbm( vec2 p )
{
    float f = 0.0;

    f += 0.700000*noise( p + iTime *0.01  ); p = mtx*p*2.02;
    f += 0.001250*noise( p ); p = mtx*p*2.01;
    f += 0.250000*noise( p ); p = mtx*p*2.03;
    f += 0.025000*noise( p ); p = mtx*p*2.01;
    f += 0.062500*noise( p ); p = mtx*p*2.04;
    f += 0.015625*noise( p + sin(iTime*0.01) );

    return f/0.96875;
}

float pattern( in vec2 p )
{
    return fbm( p + fbm( p + fbm( p ) ) );
}
// out vec4 gl_fragColor;
// vec4 gl_fragColor;
void main()
{
    updateVars();
    vec2 uv = vUv;
    float shade = pattern(uv);
    
    //BREAK
    vec2 p = (vUv) * 2.0 - 1.0;
    vec2 xy = p * vec2(iResolution.x / iResolution.y, 1);

    vec2 velocity = texture2D(u_velocity, xy).xy;
    float density = texture2D(u_density, xy).x+sin(iTime*0.01);

    // Advection
    vec2 advection = texture2D(u_velocity, xy - u_dt * velocity).xy;

    // Diffusion
    vec2 diffusion = (texture2D(u_velocity, xy + vec2(u_diff, 0.1)).xy +
                          texture2D(u_velocity, xy - vec2(u_diff, 0.1)).xy +
    texture2D(u_velocity, xy + vec2(1.0, u_diff)).xy +
    texture2D(u_velocity, xy - vec2(1.0, u_diff)).xy) / 4.0;

    // Viscosity
    vec2 viscosity = (texture2D(u_velocity, xy + vec2(u_visc, 0.1)).xy +
                      texture2D(u_velocity, xy - vec2(u_visc, 0.1)).xy +
                      texture2D(u_velocity, xy + vec2(0.1, u_visc)).xy +
                      texture2D(u_velocity, xy - vec2(0.1, u_visc)).xy -
                      4.0 * texture2D(u_velocity, xy).xy) / (u_visc * u_visc);

    // Update velocity and density
    velocity = advection + diffusion + viscosity;
    density = texture2D(u_density, xy - u_dt * velocity).x;
    
    gl_fragColor = vec4(colormap(shade).rgb * (density+0.1), shade);
    // return gl_fragColor;
}`
```

I am getting the following error:

```
three.min.js:92 THREE.WebGLProgram: shader error:  0 gl.VALIDATE_STATUS false gl.getProgramInfoLog Fragment shader is not compiled.
  ERROR: 0:252: 'gl_fragColor' : undeclared identifier
ERROR: 0:252: 'assign' : l-value required (can't modify a const)
ERROR: 0:252: '=' : dimension mismatch
ERROR: 0:252: 'assign' : cannot convert from 'highp 4-component vector of float' to 'const highp float'
```

Edit #2: I've resolved both issues above, but am still getting no output from the following code:

```
        // import * as THREE from 'three';

        // import Stats from 'three/addons/libs/stats.module.js';
        // import { GUI } from 'three/addons/libs/lil-gui.module.min.js';
        var start = new Date();
        const container = document.body;

        const FOV = 45;
        const NEAR = 0.1;
        const FAR = 1000;
        let height = container.clientHeight;
        let width = container.clientWidth;
        const ASPECT = width / height;

        const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true });
        renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio || 1);
        renderer.setClearColor(0x000000);

        const canvas = renderer.domElement;

        let scene = new THREE.Scene();

        const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(FOV, ASPECT, NEAR, FAR);
        camera.position.set(-2, 2, 2);
        camera.target = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0);
        let theta = 0;
        const radius = 100;
        const resolution = new THREE.Vector2(width, height);
        const matNormal = new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial();

        const floorGeo = new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry(2.0, 2.0);
        const floor = new THREE.Mesh(floorGeo, matNormal);
        floor.position.set(0, -0.5, 0);
        floor.rotation.x = -((Math.PI * 90) / 180);

        const sphereGeo = new THREE.SphereBufferGeometry(0.5, 32, 32);
        const sphere = new THREE.Mesh(sphereGeo, matNormal);

        scene.add(floor);
        scene.add(sphere);
        scene.add(camera);
        var elapsed = new Date() - start;
       
        const VERTEX = `
varying vec2 vUv;

void main() {
    vec4 mvPosition = modelViewMatrix * vec4(position, 1.);
    gl_Position = projectionMatrix * mvPosition;
    vUv = uv;
}
`;
const FRAGMENT = `//Adapted from https://www.shadertoy.com/view/tdG3Rd#

varying vec2 vUv;

uniform float iTime;
uniform sampler2D tDiffuse;
uniform vec2 iResolution;
// Inputs
uniform sampler2D u_velocity;
uniform sampler2D u_density;

//Other
float u_dt;
float u_diff;
float u_visc;
float prevTime;
float currTime;

void updateVars(){
    u_dt = currTime - prevTime;
    u_diff = sin(iTime*0.01);
    u_visc = 1.0;
    prevTime = currTime;
    currTime = iTime*0.01;
    
}
float colormap_red(float x) {
    if (x < 0.0) {
        return 0.0 / 255.0;
    } else if (x < 20049.0 / 82979.0) {
        return (95.79 * x + 54.51) / 255.0;
    } else {
        return 0.5;
    }
}

float colormap_green(float x) {
    if (x < 20049.0 / 82979.0) {
        return 0.2;
    } else if (x < 327013.0 / 810990.0) {
        return (8546482679670.0 / 10875673217.0 * x - 2064961390770.0 / 10875673217.0) / 255.0;
    } else if (x <= 1.0) {
        return (1038067.0 / 483977.0 * x + 19607415.0 / 483977.0) / 255.0;
    } else {
        return 0.4;
    }
}

float colormap_blue(float x) {
    if (x < 0.0) {
        return 95.0 / 255.0;
    } else if (x < 7249.0 / 82979.0) {
        return (8299.79 * x + 54.51) / 255.0;
    } else if (x < 20049.0 / 82979.0) {
        return 127.0 / 255.0;
    } else if (x < 327013.0 / 810990.0) {
        return (7922.02249341361393720147485376583 * x - 64.364790735602331034989206222672) / 255.0;
    } else {
        return 1.0;
    }
}

vec4 colormap(float x) {
    return vec4(colormap_red(x), colormap_green(x), colormap_blue(x), 1.0);
}

// https://iquilezles.org/articles/warp
/*float noise(vec2 x )
{
    vec2 p = floor(x);
    vec2 f = fract(x);
    f = f*f*(3.0-2.0*f);
    float a = texture2D(iChannel0,(p+vec2(0.5,0.5),lod)/256.0,0.0).x;
    float b = texture2D(iChannel0,(p+vec2(1.5,0.5),lod)/256.0,0.0).x;
    float c = texture2D(iChannel0,(p+vec2(0.5,1.5),lod)/256.0,0.0).x;
    float d = texture2D(iChannel0,(p+vec2(1.5,1.5),lod)/256.0,0.0).x;
    return mix(mix( a, b,f.x), mix( c, d,f.x),f.y);
}*/


float rand(vec2 n) { 
    return fract(sin(dot(n, vec2(18.9898, 14.1414))) * 43758.5453);
}

float noise(vec2 p){
    vec2 ip = floor(p);
    vec2 u = fract(p);
    u = u*u*(3.0-2.0*u);

    float res = mix(
        mix(rand(ip),rand(ip+vec2(1.0,0.0)),u.x),
        mix(rand(ip+vec2(0.0,1.0)),rand(ip+vec2(1.0,1.0)),u.x),u.y);
    return res*res;
}

const mat2 mtx = mat2( 0.80,  0.60, -0.60,  0.80 );

float fbm( vec2 p )
{
    float f = 0.0;

    f += 0.700000*noise( p + iTime *0.01  ); p = mtx*p*2.02;
    f += 0.001250*noise( p ); p = mtx*p*2.01;
    f += 0.250000*noise( p ); p = mtx*p*2.03;
    f += 0.025000*noise( p ); p = mtx*p*2.01;
    f += 0.062500*noise( p ); p = mtx*p*2.04;
    f += 0.015625*noise( p + sin(iTime*0.01) );

    return f/0.96875;
}

float pattern( in vec2 p )
{
    return fbm( p + fbm( p + fbm( p ) ) );
}
// out vec4 gl_fragColor;
// vec4 gl_fragColor;
void main()
{
    updateVars();
    vec2 uv = vUv;
    float shade = pattern(uv);
    
    //BREAK
    vec2 p = (vUv) * 2.0 - 1.0;
    vec2 xy = p * vec2(iResolution.x / iResolution.y, 1);

    vec2 velocity = texture2D(u_velocity, xy).xy;
    float density = texture2D(u_density, xy).x+sin(iTime*0.01);

    // Advection
    vec2 advection = texture2D(u_velocity, xy - u_dt * velocity).xy;

    // Diffusion
    vec2 diffusion = (texture2D(u_velocity, xy + vec2(u_diff, 0.1)).xy +
                          texture2D(u_velocity, xy - vec2(u_diff, 0.1)).xy +
    texture2D(u_velocity, xy + vec2(1.0, u_diff)).xy +
    texture2D(u_velocity, xy - vec2(1.0, u_diff)).xy) / 4.0;

    // Viscosity
    vec2 viscosity = (texture2D(u_velocity, xy + vec2(u_visc, 0.1)).xy +
                      texture2D(u_velocity, xy - vec2(u_visc, 0.1)).xy +
                      texture2D(u_velocity, xy + vec2(0.1, u_visc)).xy +
                      texture2D(u_velocity, xy - vec2(0.1, u_visc)).xy -
                      4.0 * texture2D(u_velocity, xy).xy) / (u_visc * u_visc);

    // Update velocity and density
    velocity = advection + diffusion + viscosity;
    density = texture2D(u_density, xy - u_dt * velocity).x;
    
    gl_FragColor = vec4(colormap(shade).rgb * (density+0.1), shade);

}`;

        function onWindowResize() {

            camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
            camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

            renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
            pass.uniforms.iResolution.value.set(width, height);
        }

        //

        const material = {
            uniforms: {
                tDiffuse: { type: 't', value: null },
                iResolution: { type: 'v2', value: resolution },
                iTime: {type: 'f', value: elapsed},
                iChannel0:  { type: 't', value: THREE.TextureLoader( '../static/opengl-threejs/noise.png') },
                u_velocity: { type: 'f', value: null },
                u_density: { type: 'f', value: null },
            },
            vertexShader: VERTEX,
            fragmentShader: FRAGMENT,
        };

        const composer = new THREE.EffectComposer(renderer);
        composer.addPass(new THREE.RenderPass(scene, camera));

        const pass = new THREE.ShaderPass(material);
        pass.renderToScreen = true;
        composer.addPass(pass);
        

        const resize = (width, height) => {
        camera.aspect = width / height;
        camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

        composer.setSize(width, height);

        renderer.setSize(width, height);
        };
        
        let mesh = new THREE.Mesh(sphere, material);
        mesh.position.x = 0;
        var loader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
        loader.load(modelPath, function(object) {

          // if you want to add your custom material
          var materialObj = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
              vertexColors: THREE.FaceColors,
              overdraw: 0.5
          });
           mesh.traverse(function(child) {
              if (child instanceof THREE.Mesh) {
                  child.material = materialObj;
              }
          });
      
          // then directly add the object
          scene.add(mesh);
      });

        
        const render = () => {
                 
   
            const tmpHeight = container.clientHeight;
            const tmpWidth = container.clientWidth;
            if (tmpHeight !== height || tmpWidth !== width) {
            height = tmpHeight;
            width = tmpWidth;
            resize(width, height);
            }

            renderer.render(scene, camera);
            composer.render();
            var elapsed = new Date() - start;
            requestAnimationFrame(render);
            
        };
        render();
```

Comment: Here are a few answers to this same problem: [How to implement a ShaderToy shader in three.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24820004/how-to-implement-a-shadertoy-shader-in-three-js)

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @Marquizzo thank you, that was pretty helpful! I had to tweak some of my code but am still having issues with my fragment shader compiling. It claims that gl_fragColor is an unknown identifier, though when I go to define it with 'out', it gives me the error that only GLSL ES 3.00 and above supports that.

Comment: Why are you sending null values for tDiffuse, u_velocity and u_density? Why are you setting u_velocity and u_density as floats when they should be textures? If I were you, I would just get a basic colour outputting first then add each part in stages so it is easier to debug.

Comment: Thank you for all your help and suggestions! I ended up using [this tutorial](https://medium.com/hackernoon/converting-shaders-from-shadertoy-to-threejs-fe17480ed5c6) and just pasting in my migrated shadertoy code into the fragment shader, and it works!!